# Installing Debian 8 on a Vista-windows free partition - and DRDY ERR

Tags: linux, windows-vista, debian-jessie, mmc

Being at a friends house on his computer (Medion i386) I was installing Debian 8 LINUX (i386) from a netinst-CD on a Win-Vista partition which I freed before via MMC ... The installation was successful however at the beginning of the CD-boot process I got console-messages like ATA2.00 status DRDY ERR (or similar) ... however I did not care about that because the installation went on smoothely furtheron ... I finally installed the GRUB for booting into Linux ... and rebooted the machine.

Now a similar error message occurred like above:

```
[... ]ata2.00: status: (DRDY ERR). 
[... ]ata 2.00: exeption Emask
[... ]0x0 SAct 0x0 SErt 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
etc.
```

And - linux did not come up ... only these strange endless error messages.

My questions:
Is there a way to repair procedure to this behaviour?

I would really appreciate a concise answer on this problem

Comment: I've been getting these errors for at least a year now, but Linux boots fine. I'm not sure what causes them, but I'm afraid it might be a red herring...

Comment: yeah, this one is not booting!

Comment: Medion eventually gave me the requested information: 
The Main board is a "MCP79MH" from NVIDIA ... Anybody knows how to "classify" this very strange error

Comment: I posted this error also in a Ubuntu linux page ...
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+question/280383